# WebAPI confirmation of response received

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Client requests the data from server *(which has Asp.Net WebApi)* 
and server returns the result.

Is there a way to confirm that client actually received the response when you don't have the control of client (I mean, I can't make client to send the confirmation)

**Possible scenario** client lost its internet access before it receives the package.

Comment: Why should the server care? Isn't it the responsibility of the client to retry in case of failure? (You might have a good reason, I'm just wondering.)

Comment: Why not just have another WebApi method to allow a client to confirm receipt. You would need to use a correlation id, like a GUID or something.

Comment: @Stijn it is about to know when it is not working precisely for legal reasons.  
Donal as I stated, I can't make client to send the confirmation. (that's the point of this question)

Comment: Well, if you really want to go down that road. You need to look at the request\ack pattern. http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/13/request-acknowledge-poll-with-nservicebus-and-aspnet-webapi/

Comment: @Donal It sounds close to what I'm looking for, I will test it. Thank you!

Comment: But request/ack process would require changes in client anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP protocol does no allow "client finished processing response" confirmation for single request. You need to build your own multi-request handshake.

Note: since you've mentioned "precisely for legal reasons" you need to consult lawyer before trying to implement solution.